# Javascripts files are not found when creating virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a web application which is built using ASP.NET MVC2 on Visual Studio 2008
Everything running fine.
Now I want to run the app under the local IIS server.
So I have created a virtual directory under default website in IIS.
Now When trying to run the application, the login screen should appear and it is appearing.
I have these following references inside head tag:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>TouchCast Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/ext-3.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/ext-3.2.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/ext-3.2.1/ext-all.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/TouchCastMain/login/login.js"></script>  
</head>
```

It seems that the javascripts files are not found. Now when I see the page source using "view source" and click on the links, i see it is saying the error "404 Not found".
It happens for the js files but i see the style sheet.

One more observation is:
I published my web site and put the files directly under default website without creating a virtual directory, everything works fine.

I am really in hurry. Is there any one who can help me to resolve this issue?

Regards,
Mohin

Answer (score 1):

You should use [UrlHepler.Content() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi i fixed the issue like this: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/ext-3.2.1/ext-all.js") %>"></script>